# Calculating circular heading difference treated as linear

Tags: r

I have GPS tracking data with heading and I want to calculate the change in heading by day to see if the animal is moving in one direction over a long distance (for migration). My data looks like this

```
individual.id date          heading   
1             2020-12-16    150          
1             2021-02-15    352            
1             2021-10-27    211             
1             2021-10-28    22             
1             2021-10-29    235              
1             2021-10-30    340            
1             2021-11-02    5
```

So I tried the circular function from package "circular" and this is what I ran

```
direction <- df %>% group_by(individual.id) %>% 
  mutate(heading = circular(heading, units = "degrees", template= "geographics"),
        heading.diff=heading-lag(heading))
```

and the result

```
individual.id date          heading    heading.diff
1             2020-12-16    150         NA         
1             2021-02-15    352        202         
1             2021-10-27    211        141         
1             2021-10-28    22         189         
1             2021-10-29    235        213         
1             2021-10-30    340        105         
1             2021-11-02    5          335
```

The problem is that heading starts and end at 0/360 degrees, meaning if a point is at 340, it can turn to 5 degrees with only a 25 degree angle, but the calculation goes the 'long' way around by going anti-clockwise to the next angle instead of the shorter way through 0/360 (i.e. 335 degrees). It gives the same results when it is treated as a linear value like this command

```
direction <- df%>% group_by(individual.id) %>% 
  mutate(heading.diff=abs(heading-lag(heading)))
```

But the correct values should be like this

```
individual.id date          heading    heading.diff
1             2020-12-16    150         NA         
1             2021-02-15    352        158         
1             2021-10-27    211        141         
1             2021-10-28    22         171         
1             2021-10-29    235        147         
1             2021-10-30    340        105         
1             2021-11-02    5          25
```

Is there a way to calculate the difference in heading properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider each of the possible cases and just choose the smallest

```
df %>% 
  group_by(individual.id) %>% 
  mutate(heading.diff=pmin(
    abs(heading -lag(heading) + 360), 
    abs(heading - lag(heading)), 
    abs(heading - lag(heading) - 360)))

#   individual.id date       heading heading.diff
#           <int> <chr>        <int>        <dbl>
# 1             1 2020-12-16     150           NA
# 2             1 2021-02-15     352          158
# 3             1 2021-10-27     211          141
# 4             1 2021-10-28      22          171
# 5             1 2021-10-29     235          147
# 6             1 2021-10-30     340          105
# 7             1 2021-11-02       5           25
```